# Breakpoint triggered when freeing a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, binary-tree

I'm writing a binary search tree for a class and I probably am doing something wrong but it's beyond my skill to determine what.

Here's the node structure:

```
typedef struct Node {
  int value;
  struct Node *left;
  struct Node *right;
} Node, *NodePtr;
```

Here's my create node function:

```
NodePtr nodeCreate(int value) {
  NodePtr node_new = 0;
  node_new = (NodePtr) malloc(sizeof node_new);
  node_new->value = value;
  node_new->left = 0;
  node_new->right = 0;
  return node_new;
}
```

And my destroy the whole tree function:

```
void treeDestroy(NodePtr root) {
  if (!root) { return; } 
    treeDestroy(root->left); 
    treeDestroy(root->right);
    free(root); // HERE IS WHERE MY BREAKPOINT TRIGGERS
    root = 0;
}
```

Finally here's what my main looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  NodePtr tree_root = 0;
  tree_root = nodeCreate(2);
  tree_root->left = nodeCreate(1);
  tree_root->right = nodeCreate(3);
  treePrint(tree_root);
  treeDestroy(tree_root);
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me find what's wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

```
  node_new = (NodePtr) malloc(sizeof node_new);
```

should be

```
  node_new = malloc(sizeof *node_new);
```

`sizeof node_new` is size of `pointer` where as `sizeof *node_new` is size of object which pointer is pointing.

Comment: Makes sense, can't believe I missed it! Thanks!

Comment: @void-main-void No problem.